# How to delete ALL rows that contain a non numeric value

Tags: vba, excel

I Have a sheet That looks like this with filled columns ..

```
                       Column B     Column C     Column D
row 2 : Product 1      100          200          300
row 3 : Product 2      100          200A         100
row 4 : Product 3      AAA          200          300
row 5 : Product 4      600          200          300
row 6 : Product 5      150          200          300,2A
```

What I want is : 
for each row, if columnB's value is not numeric or columnC's value is not numeric or columnD's value is not numeric, delete that row.

This is my code, that looks fine to me :

```
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Set xWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
lastrow = xWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    BValue = xWs.Range("B" & i).Value
    CValue = xWs.Range("C" & i).Value
    DValue = xWs.Range("D" & i).Value
    If Not IsNumeric(BValue) Or Not IsNumeric(CValue) Or Not IsNumeric(DValue) Then
         xWs.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

My problem is : When i execute the code .. It deletes the rows number 4 and 6 but leave row number 3 eventhough the columnB value is not a numeric ..

I can't figure out the problem .. 
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Union and delete in one go to avoid skipping rows by deleting rows in an upward fashion. You should delete rows going backwards.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim xWs As Worksheet, i As Long, lastRow As Long, unionRng As Range
Set xWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
lastRow = xWs.Cells(xWs.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim BValue As Variant, CValue As Variant, DValue As Variant

For i = 2 To lastRow
    BValue = xWs.Range("B" & i).Value
    CValue = xWs.Range("C" & i).Value
    DValue = xWs.Range("D" & i).Value
    If Not IsNumeric(BValue) Or Not IsNumeric(CValue) Or Not IsNumeric(DValue) Then
        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
            Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, xWs.Rows(i))
        Else
            Set unionRng = xWs.Rows(i)
        End If

    End If
Next i

If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.Delete

End Sub
```

Or going backwards:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim xWs As Worksheet, i As Long, lastRow As Long, unionRng As Range
Set xWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
lastRow = xWs.Cells(xWs.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim BValue As Variant, CValue As Variant, DValue As Variant

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    BValue = xWs.Range("B" & i).Value
    CValue = xWs.Range("C" & i).Value
    DValue = xWs.Range("D" & i).Value
    If Not IsNumeric(BValue) Or Not IsNumeric(CValue) Or Not IsNumeric(DValue) Then xWs.Rows(i).Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a remark .. maybe you'll want to add an 'end if' before 'next i' in your second code .. ^^ Thanks Again ..

Comment: Hi, If the IF statement is on one line then it doesn't get terminated with End If. End If is for multi-line IF statements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fastest way which doesn't loop through rows... It uses `SpecialCells` and `Autofilter`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, delRng As Range, totRng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("B2:D" & lRow)
        Set totRng = .Range("B1:D" & lRow)

        On Error Resume Next
        Set delRng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If delRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub _
        Else delRng.ClearContents

        For i = 1 To 3
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            With totRng
                .AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="="
                .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**My Assumptions (Change as applicable)**

1. Row 1 has headers
2. Col B,C,D have same last row
3. Code Name of the sheet is `Sheet1`

**Visual Explanation**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. it is not working as expected .. it deletes even rows that contain numeric values ..

Comment: If your number is stored as text then they will get deleted

Comment: I found out the problem .. the line : Set totRng = .Range("B1:D" & lRow) in your code should be : Set totRng = .Range("B2:D" & lRow) since my data starts from row 2 .. Now it is working good .. Thank Youuu ! ^^